# Cause: aidl is missing from 'E:\Linux Data\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aidl.exe'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am unable to find the solution. 
How can I fix it.
This error occurs after updating the android studio from 3.0 to 3.1.3...

Comment: I have the same problem, waiting for the answer

Comment: I now realized that in your path "Linux Data" contains a space just like my path. could this be the problem?

Comment: I have found the solution. 
Actually the sdk path I am trying to set is Linux's android studio sdk. now I want that in windows I have download the fresh one and the issue resolved

Comment: My solution is this: adding 'buildToolsVersion: "28.0.0" ' into the build.gradle file (which was not there anymore with Android Studio 3) although compileSdkVersion is 27. Strange.